# How to select an image button and onMouseOver display div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this structure (from **markItUp** plugin):

[image: structure]

It's image button with CSS a:hover element. I want to put **jQuery** so when user mouse-over that button, another panel shows underneath (with 9 more buttons) to click on. Something like this:

[image]

How to select that thing with jQuery?

For showing/hiding the panel I would use this code

```
jQuery('body').append("<div id='panel' style='display: none;'>9 buttons inside this div</div>");
    jQuery('that.button').hover(function() {
          jQuery('#panel').show();
    }, function() {
          jQuery('#panel').hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you need to add id attribute to li for the buttons and use jquery to select a single element with the given id attribute.

```
<li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton1 link" id="button1">...</li>
<li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton2 link" id="button2">...</li>
<li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton3 link" id="button3">...</li>
```

Use this to select and do action on hover for each button,

```
jQuery('#button1').hover(function() {
    your_code_here
}
```

Comment: Can I do it without assigning ID's?

Comment: class attribute is for selecting a set of elements; if you want to select on button and do some action you will need id's

Comment: Every button has it's own class (differentiating at the number at the end) so that should also work or...? (like it has own id)

Comment: It could work if there is only one button with that class on that page, and if that is the case it should be an id not a class. So, if possible make markItUpButton1, markItUpButton2, markItUpButton3, ... as id's and select using id's.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this: http://api.jquery.com/hover/
Like in the example:

```
$("#someid").hover(
  function () {
    //show or hide your panel
  }
 );
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use the class attribute with the specific button number.
If you look at the HTML, each button has a button number associated with it.You can use this to determine the button.

```
    // on function in jQuery works for dynamically added elements
    (". markItUpButton1").on("mouseenter", function(){
        // Add function to show panel here
    });
```

If you want to target all buttons, you can use the 'markItUpButton' class and then determine based on the button content what panel to show.

Reference:
http://api.jquery.com/on/